# Android ksoap2 send envelope with empty body?

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, ksoap

I want to send an envelope with an empty body like this:

```
     <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
     xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <v:Header />
        <v:Body>
        </v:Body>
     </v:Envelope>
```

Is it possible and how? I've tried with this:

```
     HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(HOST, PORT, ENDPOINT, TIMEOUT);
     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(null, null);
     SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);    
     envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
     transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do it, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by creating my own SoapSerializationEnvelope extending the original one and overridering the writeBody method with this:
public class MySoapEnvelope extends SoapSerializationEnvelope

```
{   
    public MySoapEnvelope(int version) {
        super(version);
    }
    @Override
    public void writeBody(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException
    {
        if (bodyOut!=null){
        super.writeBody(writer);
        }   
    }
}
```

To use it, you just have to use the MySoapSerializationEnvelope and set envelope.bodyOut=null;

```
HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(host, port, endpoint, timeout);
MySoapEnvelope emptySoapEnvelope = new MySoapEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
emptySoapEnvelope.bodyOut = null;
transport.call(methodname, emptySoapEnvelope);
```

I dont know if you want to cut a new release with this code. I would  possibly make a new method in the original SoapEnvelope called setEmptyEnvelope(). But that's up to you. 
You could get along with this, but then you should make a respectable
documentation so people would know this is how it's done.

Comment: Does this works on ksoap 3.2? I've tried to use it but am still sending empty tag inside the body tag.
Like:
<v:Body>
 < />
</v:Body>

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. You might want to debug into the framework to see what is going on. If you can create a fix for it I am happy to pull it into upstream and cut a new release.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by creating mt own SoapSerializationEnvelope extending the original one and overridering the writeBody method with this:
`@Override
 public void writeBody(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException
 {
  if (bodyOut!=null){
  super.writeBody(writer);
  } 
  
 }`